After scaling the glyphs using fontforge getting issues while rendering in html
After scaling the glyphs using the below steps:
used emsize 1024
1.From the menu in the font window pick Edit -> Select -> Select all (or type Control-A)
2.Pick Element -> Transformations -> Transform (or type Control-backslash)
3.Set "Glyph Origin" as the Origin and pick "Scale Uniformly..." in the next drop-down. Enter the desired scale factor (out of 100).
Recommended: Leave the first two boxes unchecked but check the last four.
4.Hit "OK" and wait for the transformation process to complete.
5.Save the file and generate the fonts as needed.
(https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/3421)
getting height issues while rendering the ttf file in html
getting height issues between each glyph while rendering in html

image_1
image_2
img_3: fontsize 13
img4: fontsize 12, height of u

kindly help me in fixing the height of the font`

You probably need to update or regenerate the hinting instructions (responsible for optimized pixel-grid-fitting when rendering). Not familiar with fontforge but I assume it removes the present hinting data when scaling glyphs. You probably don't notice height differences in larger font sizes.
